# Why does a matrix column being a multiple of another imply that the matrix is singular?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> **Q:** If a matrix of order $9$ has a column that is a multiple of another,
>   does the system $Ax = 0$ has infinite solutions?
>
> ---
>
> **A:** Yes, because the matrix would not be invertible.

Can you explain this answer further?

I understand that the matrix needs to be invertible in order to have an unique solution, but how do you know that having a column that is a multiple of another causes the matrix to be singular? Does the same happen with rows?

Comment: Suppose that colum $C_i$ is a multiple of column $C_j$, say $M=(C_1\mid \cdots\mid C_i\mid\cdots\mid \lambda C_i\mid \cdots\mid C_n)$. If $x=\sum a_ie_i$ is any vector, $Mx=\sum a_iC_i$, so what choice of $x$ (nonzero!) makes $Mx=0$?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the column $c_i$ of $A$ is equal to the columns $c_j$ times $\alpha$ so we have

$$Ae_i=\alpha A e_j$$
where $(e_1,\ldots,e_9)$ is the standard basis, hence
$$A(\beta(e_i-\alpha e_j))=0,\quad \forall \beta\in\Bbb R $$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the $i$-th column is $k$ times the $j$-th column. Consider (the $'$ below denotes transposition so that $x$ is a column vector):
$$
x=r(0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots,-k,\ldots,0)'
$$
where $r\in\mathbb{R}$ and the $1$ is in the $i$-th position and the $-k$ is in the $j$-th position and everywhere else is $0$. Can you see that for all $r\in\mathbb{R}$, you have $Ax=0$?

If $A$ were invertible, then $0=Ax\implies 0=(A^{-1})0=(A^{-1})Ax=x$ so $x=0$ would be the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $A^{T}$. Perform an elementary row operation on it (two rows of $A^{T}$ are multiple of one another, so replace one by itself plus a multiple of the other) to get a matrix $B$, which has a  zero row. Then $\det (A) = \det (A^{T}) = \det (B) = 0$, the latter is seen to be zero via expanding along the zero row.